# alternative approach to setup github project with git clone

Tags: networking, github, open-source, firewall

For some projects stored on github.com, they suggest the following commands for setup,

```
Clone this repository: git clone https://github.com/projectA/projectA.git
Initialize all submodules: git submodule update --init --recursive
```

My development environment is built on the enterprise network behind the firewall, which does not allow me to use `git clone` and `git submodule`. With respect to this kind of scenario, what are the alternate approach to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and clone a repo at home, use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) in order to generate *one* file (with all the repo history in it) and copy that file somewhere accessible from your enterprise network.

That way, you can clone from that file, and still get the repo full history.